# StartScreenCapturebyWindowId() not excluding overlapping windows for certain programs (Agora Unity)

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, agora.io

I am trying to setup individual window sharing for a project in Unity for Windows. The way I'm currently going about doing this is by using `EnumWindows()`, `IsVisableWindow()`, and `GetWindowText()` to create a dictionary of window titles and handles, then calling `StartScreeCapturebyWindowId()` to share the selected window.

This works relatively well for most process; the window of the process and only the window of the process is streamed. However, for certain programs (like Google Chrome, Discord, and Windows Photos) the captured area is set correctly, but overlapping windows are not culled out.

Does anyone know what could be causing this problem? Is there something wrong with the way I'm grabbing the handles for these windows? Or is there something about starting a screen capture that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly did the correct things.  However, you also hit the limitation to the Windows part of the SDK. To understand this better, the set of programs are UWP applications. They have different ways to share the visible pixels.  Previously version of Agora SDK could not even show the window.  Starting from 3.0.1, the SDK uses Rectangle cutting method to get the window display. You may further read the online documentation about that API [here](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/unity/classagora__gaming__rtc_1_1_i_rtc_engine.html#aab2aacc7ef350f54010002fcfe2554ae).

There isn't much Agora can do for the near term.  So you will just need to deal with the user experience (e.g. by warning them) or look at solutions like using Web SDK instead.